ESO Instrument pipeline problems with running pycpl and pyesorex
I need to install the European Southern Observatory (ESO) software to reduce spectra from the Giraffe instrument on the VLT.
The ESO labels for the code are 'CPL' and 'ESOREX' and the python based plug-ins are 'pycpl' and 'pyesorex'.
I've tried the instructions on the ESO website as well as the associated sites for the Python code, however there always seems to be a glitch which stops the software running into my linux machine using Ubuntu 24.04 even though I'm pretty sure I've followed all the installation and run steps.
I'm no wizz with this kind of stuff so I thought I'd give this forum a try.
Would anyone who is comfortable with this sort of thing have either a step-by step 'Dummies' guide I could follow or some time to have a look at helping me out by putting something together?
Cheers.

Have you looked into if they run on Ubuntu 24.04?

The ESO site for installation simply states "for Ubuntu 20.04 and newer".

See if you can contact them and ask if it is ready for Ubuntu 24.04, betting it is not.

Will do - cheers.
